# how to resize an image or done as a NSAttributedString NSTextAttachment (or set its initital size)

Tags: ios, ios7, uiimage, nsattributedstring, nstextattachment

I have a NSAttributedString to which I am adding a NSTextAttachment. The image is 50w by 50h but I'd like it to scale down to reflect the line height of the attributed string. I thought this would be done automatically but I guess not. I have looked at the UImage class reference but this image doesn't seem to be set in a UIImageView so no access to a frame property. Here's a screenshot of what I currently have:

[image]

In an ideal world, I would also like to implement a way to scale up the image based upon user input (such as increasing the font size). Any ideas on how to achieve this?

thx

### edit 1

here's how I'm creating it:

```
    NSTextAttachment *textAttachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
    textAttachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"note-small.png"];
    NSLog(@"here is the scale: %f", textAttachment.image.scale);
    NSAttributedString *attrStringWithImage = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:textAttachment];
    [headerAS replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([headerAS length], 0) withString:@" "];
    [headerAS replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([headerAS length], 0) withAttributedString:attrStringWithImage];
```

Comment: It will help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26105803/center-nstextattachment-image-next-to-single-line-uilabel

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Look at subclassing `NSTextAttachment` and implementing the `NSTextAttachmentContainer` methods to return different sizes based on the text container supplied. By default, `NSTextAttachment` just returns the size of the image it is provided with.

Comment: See `attachment.bounds`

Answer (score 86):

You should set bounds form attachment to resize image like this:

`attachment.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, yourImgWidth, yourImgHeight)`

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: This solution is working well on iOS devices, but not working on macOS.

Comment: I found a way to force update the size of image attachment on macOS. I'm appending that as a new answer to this question.

Answer (score 34):

If you need to resize a bunch of `NSTextAttachment` images while keeping their aspect ratio i've written a handy extension: http://hack.swic.name/convenient-nstextattachment-image-resizing

```
extension NSTextAttachment {
    func setImageHeight(height: CGFloat) {
        guard let image = image else { return }
        let ratio = image.size.width / image.size.height

        bounds = CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x, y: bounds.origin.y, width: ratio * height, height: height)
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
let textAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
textAttachment.image = UIImage(named: "Image")
textAttachment.setImageHeight(16) // Whatever you need to match your font

let imageString = NSAttributedString(attachment: textAttachment)
yourAttributedString.appendAttributedString(imageString)
```

Comment: that link doesn't seem to be accessible any more…

Comment: Yes it went down with nosupportlinuxhosting unfortunately. But i believe the code in this post is everything there was to it.

Comment: I created a `setImageWidth` as well, but it's pretty self-explanatory

Answer (score 3):

**Swift4**
if you want a attributed string along with the image or a icon

**here you can do something like this.**

```html
func AttributedTextwithImgaeSuffixAndPrefix(AttributeImage1 : UIImage , AttributedText : String ,AttributeImage2 : UIImage,  LabelBound : UILabel) -> NSMutableAttributedString
{
    let fullString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "  ")
    let image1Attachment = NSTextAttachment()
    image1Attachment.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: ((LabelBound.font.capHeight) - AttributeImage1.size.height).rounded() / 2, width: AttributeImage1.size.width, height: AttributeImage1.size.height)
    image1Attachment.image = AttributeImage1
    let image1String = NSAttributedString(attachment: image1Attachment)
    let image2Attachment = NSTextAttachment()
    image2Attachment.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: ((LabelBound.font.capHeight) - AttributeImage2.size.height).rounded() / 2, width: AttributeImage2.size.width, height: AttributeImage2.size.height)
    image2Attachment.image = AttributeImage2
    let image2String = NSAttributedString(attachment: image2Attachment)
    fullString.append(image1String)
    fullString.append(NSAttributedString(string: AttributedText))
    fullString.append(image2String)
    return fullString
}
```

you can use this code as mentioned below:

```html
        self.lblMid.attributedText = AttributedTextwithImgaeSuffixAndPrefix(AttributeImage1: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Left") , AttributedText: "  Payment Details  ", AttributeImage2: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "RIght") , LabelBound: self.lblMid)
```

here you can add images you can replace it with your own:

Left Image
[image]

Right Image
[image]

Out put will be like this [image]

Answer (score 0):

NSTextAtatchment is just a holder for a UIImage so scale the image when it needs scaling and recreate the text attachment or set it's image. You'll need to force a nslayout update if you change the image on an existing text attachment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Dung Nguyen, for his answer. I found that his solution works well on iOS devices, but not working on macOS when trying to update an attachment in a large NSAttributedString. So I searched for my own solution for that. Here it is

```
let newSize: NSSize = \\ the new size for the image attachment
let originalAttachment: NSTextAttachment = \\ wherever the attachment comes from
let range: NSRange = \\ the range of the original attachment in a wholeAttributedString object which is an NSMutableAttributedString
if originalAttachment.fileWrapper != nil, 
   originalAttachment.fileWrapper!.isRegularFile {
    if let contents = originalAttachment.fileWrapper!.regularFileContents {
        let newAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
        newAttachment.image = NSImage(data: contents)
        #if os(iOS)
        newAttachment.fileType = originalAttachment.fileType
        newAttachment.contents = originalAttachment.contents
        newAttachment.fileWrapper = originalAttachment.fileWrapper
        #endif
        newAttachment.bounds = CGRect(x: originalAttachment.bounds.origin.x, 
                                      y: originalAttachment.bounds.origin.y, 
                                      width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height)
        let newAttachmentString = NSAttributedString(attachment: newAttachment)
        wholeAttributedString.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: newAttachmentString)
    }
}
```

Also, on different OS, the image size or bounds an image attachment returns can be different. In order to extract the correct image size, I wrote the following extensions:

```
extension FileWrapper {
    
    func imageSize() -> CPSize? {
        if self.isRegularFile {
            if let contents = self.regularFileContents {
                if let image: CPImage = CPImage(data: contents) {
                    #if os(iOS)
                    return image.size
                    #elseif os(OSX)
                    if let rep = image.representations.first {
                        return NSMakeSize(CGFloat(rep.pixelsWide),
                                          CGFloat(rep.pixelsHigh))
                    }
                    #endif
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}

extension NSTextAttachment {
    
    func imageSize() -> CPSize? {
        var imageSize: CPSize?
        if self.fileType != nil && 
           AttachmentFileType(rawValue: self.fileType!) != nil {
            if self.bounds.size.width > 0 {
                imageSize = self.bounds.size
            } else if self.image?.size != nil {
                imageSize = self.image!.size
            } else if let fileWrapper = self.fileWrapper {
                if let imageSizeFromFileWrapper = fileWrapper.imageSize() {
                    imageSize = imageSizeFromFileWrapper
                }
            }
        }
        return imageSize
    }
}

#if os(iOS)
    import UIKit
    public typealias CPSize = CGSize
#elseif os(OSX)
    import Cocoa
    public typealias CPSize = NSSize
#endif

#if os(iOS)
    import UIKit
    public typealias CPImage = UIImage
#elseif os(OSX)
    import AppKit
    public typealias CPImage = NSImage
#endif

enum AttachmentFileType: String {
    case jpeg = "public.jpeg"
    case jpg = "public.jpg"
    case png = "public.png"
    case gif = "public.gif"
}
```