# Resize an image that is used in NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

> Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22357171/how-to-resize-an-image-or-done-as-a-nsattributedstring-nstextattachment-or-set) but the accepted answer below is a simple one-function solution.

I'm trying to make a news article details view controller to display the article's image at the top then date then a long description.

I learned that i have to use `NSAttributedString` and only one `UITextView` in order to do that. Now everything works fine but i have only one issue now: the image width is not fitting the screen width (or the TextView  width), please see this image below:

[image: App Screenshot]

I tried everything, nothing works.

How can i make the image fit screen width ?

Thanks in advance.

**EDITED AGAIN**
This is the code that is involved:

```
#import "SingleNewsViewController.h"

@interface SingleNewsViewController ()

@end

@implementation SingleNewsViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSAttributedString *image = [self imageString];
    NSAttributedString *date = [self dateString];
    NSAttributedString *body = [self bodyString];

    NSMutableAttributedString *wholeStory = [NSMutableAttributedString new];

    // TODO: can you be sure image, date and body are all non-nil?
    NSArray *allComponents = @[image, date, body];
    for(NSAttributedString *component in allComponents)
    {
        [wholeStory appendAttributedString:component];
        if(component != [allComponents lastObject])
            [[wholeStory mutableString] appendString:@"\n\n"];
    }

    self.tv.attributedText = wholeStory;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (UIImage *)image
{
    return [UIImage imageNamed:@"latest_news_img.jpg"];
}

- (NSString *)dateText
{
    return @"Hi There, this is date!";
}

- (NSString *)bodyText
{
    return @"Hi There, this is body text!Hi There, .....";
}

- (NSAttributedString *)imageString
{
    NSTextAttachment *textAttachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
    textAttachment.image = [self image];
    return [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:textAttachment];
}

- (NSAttributedString *)dateString
{
    return [[NSAttributedString alloc]
            initWithString:[self dateText]
            /*attributes:
             @{
             NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle: UIFontTextStyleSubheadline],
             ... etc ...
             }*/];
}

- (NSAttributedString *)bodyString
{
    return [[NSAttributedString alloc]
            initWithString:[self bodyText]
            /*attributes:
             @{
             NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle: UIFontTextStyleBody],
             ... etc ...
             }*/];
}



@end
```

Comment: Set the ```UIImageView``` property to ```Scale to Fit```.

Comment: i did all this view programmatically, using NSAttributedString, not storyboard

Comment: i need a programmatic solution

Comment: Ok so then show us your code. I can't help you if I can't see whats wrong with your code.

Comment: @dan okay can you please look at my code

Comment: Yeah had a look at it. You need to then pragmatically set the aspect fit property of that image view. Try this: ```textAttachment.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;```.

Comment: @Lance exactly, so what to do ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to resize an image or done as a NSAttributedString NSTextAttachment (or set its initital size)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22357171/how-to-resize-an-image-or-done-as-a-nsattributedstring-nstextattachment-or-set)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh right, so `NSTextAttachment` doesn't have image views... ah... Right well then another idea comes to mind. How about reszing the `UIImage` data and then passing that image to the `NSTextAttachment`, like in this post:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/2658801/4657588

Make use of this method to resize the image accordingly:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    // In next line, pass 0.0 to use the current device's pixel scaling factor (and thus account for Retina resolution).
    // Pass 1.0 to force exact pixel size.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: `Property imageView not found on object of type NSTextAttachment`

Comment: because there's no image view

Comment: NSTextAttachment doesn't have an `imageView` property

Comment: @ANA ok so in that case are you adding the image view in pragmatically yourself? There must be somewhere in your code where you are doing something a long the lines of ```[self.view addSubview:myImageView]```??

Comment: @ANA show me the code you are using to add in the image view to your view. You are probably doing it in ```viewDidLoad``` or some method like that. Show me that code. I may be able to help then.

Comment: @Dan There is no imageView, that's the idea of `NSAttributedString`, let me edit the code to show you.

Comment: @Dan ok i tried it, the one in the link it works, but how to make it fit the screen, because there are several iphone screen widths ?

Comment: @Dan Actually, it worked on all screens i tested it, thanks, if you can edit your answer so i can accept it :)

Comment: @ANA That's great to hear! I updated my answer too :)

Comment: @Dan okay and delete the original code you posted for people to benefit from your second correct answer :)