# Separate detailTextLabel by an image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Im trying to do this:
 [image: http://imgur.com/ujNDgQm]

The separator needs to dynamically change with the length of the label. This is what i have now

```
UIImageView *separator = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Shuffle"]];
separator.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(cell.detailTextLabel.frame), CGRectGetHeight(cell.frame) / 2,200, 20);
[cell addSubview:separator];
```

The image is placed there but it doesn't dynamically change like I thought it would.

Comment: What's the separator in your image?

Comment: You could use "•" as your separator, or maybe `NSAttributedString` and `NSTextAttachment` .

Comment: By doing a research since there are question about that in StackOverFlow?

Comment: My mistake. I thought that by giving your two key words (`NSAttributedString` and `NSTextAttachment`), it would be enough. Here a link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22357171/how-to-resize-an-image-or-done-as-a-nsattributedstring-nstextattachment-or-set

Comment: where did u call the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want a •, simply set the label text to

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ARTIST: %@ • LENGTH: %@", artistName, formattedTimeAsString];
```

Of course you might have to use NSLocalizedString in case you support more than one language