# Resize NSTextAttachment to fit UITextView width

Tags: ios, uitextview, nstextattachment

How do I get all `NSTextAttachment`'s (and ultimately their images) to automatically resize to fit within their `UITextView`'s width?

Comment: For the resize: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22357171/how-to-resize-an-image-or-done-as-a-nsattributedstring-nstextattachment-or-set For finding them: `enumerateAttribute:inRange: options:usingBlock:` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29152660/extract-uiimage-from-nsattributed-string/29153172#29153172)

Comment: How about for the automatic?

Comment: I don't think there is an all built stuff for that.