# Replacing an image in an NSAttributedString

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring

I am trying to replace an image in an `NSAttributedString` with a scaled copy of itself (to fit a `UITextView`'s width), however, in many (not all) cases, the replaced image is a mask of the original. I assume that there is something in the other attributes of the string which is doing this as both the image extraction and the creation of a new attributed string from the image work perfectly.

Note: answers like this [how to resize an image or done as a NSAttributedString NSTextAttachment (or set its initital size)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22357171/how-to-resize-an-image-or-done-as-a-nsattributedstring-nstextattachment-or-set) show how to construct a string with images (which I can do) or how to modify the size of a text attachment (again, I can do that) prior to creating the string, but not how to modify *in place*.

**Update**
Thanks to suggestions by commentator @Larme I have now solved my original problem of resizing an image in-place by changing the original `NSTextAttachment.bounds` - note, not replacing it, changing it *in situ*. I'm not going to post that as an answer to my own question, as it doesn't answer the wider question of **replacing** an image.

Any tips as to how to proceed gratefully accepted.

Here's the basis:

```
extension NSAttributedString {
    func resizeAttachments(maxWidth: CGFloat) -> NSAttributedString {

        var replacement = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self)

        func replace(_ image: UIImage, in range: NSRange, dict: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]) {
            // ... see below for variants of this
        }

        self.enumerateAttributes(in: NSMakeRange(0, self.length),
                                 options: [],
                                 using: {dict, range, stop in
            for (key, value) in dict {
                if key == .attachment, let attachment = value as? NSTextAttachment {
                    if
                        let fw = attachment.fileWrapper, fw.isRegularFile,
                        let d = fw.regularFileContents,
                        let image = UIImage(data: d)?.resized(toWidth: maxWidth) { 
                        // removing the resize above makes no difference to the issue
                        // i.e. replacing the image with itself still causes the same problem
                        replace(image, in: range, dict: dict)
                        return // Exit the block. Can't have 2 .attachments.
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        return replacement
    }
}
```

So far, a straight forward enumeration on `self`, modifying the mutable copy string `replacement` when an image is encountered. Here's what I get:

[image]

From this unscaled original:

[image]

So, what have I tried in the replace function?

```
    func replace(_ image: UIImage, in range: NSRange, dict: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]) {
        let newAttachment = NSTextAttachment(image: image)
        let newCharacter = NSMutableAttributedString(attachment: newAttachment)
        // NB if I replace the entire string with `newCharacter` the image is perfect (but obviously the rest of the string has gone)

        // Option 1
        replacement.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: newCharacter)

        // Option 2
        var newDict: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = dict
        newDict[.attachment] = newAttachment
        replacement.addAttributes(newDict, range: range)

        // Option 3
        replacement.removeAttribute(.attachment, range: range)
        replacement.addAttribute(.attachment, value: newAttachment, range: range)

    }
```

I can't find anything anywhere about actually replacing images. As I said, the extraction of the image works fine - if I just return a new attributed string with only the extracted image then it's perfect. If I append the image to the end, it works. It's modifying it in place that seems to be the issue. Has anyone ever done this successfully?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to resize an image or done as a NSAttributedString NSTextAttachment (or set its initital size)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22357171/how-to-resize-an-image-or-done-as-a-nsattributedstring-nstextattachment-or-set)

Comment: No I don't think it does... I saw this question - the accepted answer says "subclass NSTextAttachment" (not very usefully), and the other answers are about appending the image (which I can do), not modifying it "in place" i.e. not at the start or end. It's not the resizing that's the issue, it's (I think) the effect of surrounding attributes.

Comment: What about trying changing the underlying images? And then force the attributedString to redraw?

Comment: I'll try that, thanks...

Comment: Forcing the newly created attachment bounds (`newAttachment.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: image.size)`) doesn't work? Also, a needLayout might work?

Comment: Unrelated but instead of enumerating all the attributes with `enumerateAttributes()`, you can call `enumerateAttribute(_:in:options:using:)` focusing only in attachments.

Comment: @Larme - many thanks. I have fixed my immediate problem by starting with your suggestion on `NSTextAttachment.bounds` - but not, as you suggest on the `newAttachment` but simply modifying the original attachment's bounds (d'oh! should have tried that to start with!). So I can resize the attachment, but I still can't *replace* an image... not quite sure what to do about the question, now. :)